# Unable to Generate Code First Migration Scripts during Visual Studio Team Services Build

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I want to Generate Some files during TFS-Build for e.g. Generate some text files using exe which is executed through powershell.

I added the steps(Powershell) in TFS-build Definition , when my process comes to this step, log generates and shows that file is generated successfully, but I don't see any generated file under Artifacts > drop folder.

NOTE: I am using same directory for generating text files where my exe is available.

How to achieve this in TFS Build , I am using Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: Can you show which build steps you are using and how you have configured them?

Comment: Can you provide the detail build log here?

Comment: Hi Starain / MrHinsh, Here is the link for logs : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilmqnr1whek2rin/logs_154.zip?dl=0                        I am using TFS build > Adding Build Steps .                                                                                                                        Steps for Build in screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjq0xcn251nmbn1/BuildSteps.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the log files, you just published the files that in the D:\a\1\a folder to the artifacts (e.g. CIRIg.Mvc.zip, CIRIg.Mvc.SourceManifest.xml, CIRIg.Mvc.deploy.cmd, CIRIg.Mvc.SetParameters.xml).

However, the generated txt file (636247216960041685.txt) is in the D:\a\1\s...) and isn’t copied to the D:\a\1\a folder. So, you don’t see it in Artifacts > drop folder.

To deal with that issue, you can generate the file to D:\a\1\a ($(build.artifactstagingdirectory)) folder or copy that file to that folder by using [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) step/task.

Comment: Sure Starain, will try to do same and revert back to you next week. Thanks for your response and help

Comment: Hi Starain, Now I am able to see generated files into drop folder. I used Copy Task, to copy txt files to "D:\a\1\a folder".  Thanks again. I accept this answer.